# Rename file when uploading via Pluploader classic asp

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, plupload

I´m having trouble renaming files when uploaing with pluploader.

I want the files to have the naming of user-ID, post-ID and dateTime. Like:
u12_p983_20131103_192328.jpg

This is my code right now.

```
$(function() {
var 
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'html5,gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
    browse_button : 'pickfiles',
    container : 'container',
    max_file_size : '10mb',
    url : 'add_file_upload.asp?pID=<%=pID%>&userID=<%=CookieUserID%>',
    flash_swf_url : 'includes/plupload.flash.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url : 'includes/plupload.silverlight.xap',      
    filters : [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
        {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}           
    ],
    resize : {width : 600, quality : 90}
});

uploader.bind('Init', function(up, params) {
    $('#filelist').html("<div>Current runtime: " + params.runtime + "</div>");
});

$('#uploadfiles').click(function(e) {
    uploader.start();
    e.preventDefault();
});

uploader.init();

uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
    $.each(files, function(i, file) {
        $('#filelist').append(
            '<div id="' + file.id + '">' +
            file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b>' +
        '</div>');
    });

    up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
});

uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {
    $('#' + file.id + " b").html(file.percent + "% <img height='10px' src='images/progress_bar.gif' />");
});

uploader.bind('Error', function(up, err) {
    $('#filelist').append("<div>Error: " + err.code +
        ", Message: " + err.message +
        (err.file ? ", File: " + err.file.name : "") +
        "</div>"
    );


    up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
});

uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file) {
    $('#' + file.id + " b").html("100%");

});
});
```

I've tried with `multipart_params`, but never got it to work.

Comment: Shouldn't you rename the files on server side when uploaded?

Comment: Not possible, due to security reasons file input value is read only and can't be changed by code. Do it server side.

Comment: Ok, so after uploading it would be possible to run a server-side renaming process?
Tips on how to do it serverside after upload?